# Eyes clipping through eyelids. Any solutions?

Tags: objects, rigify, clipping

I've rigged a human with [Rigify](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/rigging/rigify.html). However, when I move the eyes they clip through the eyelids.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a whole lot until I started adjusting the eye deform bones. the "tail" of that bone should be in the center of the eye sphere. The bone rotates around that point, so if the eyeball center isn't at that place (or close, I don't snap it) it'll drift when you rotate the eyes.[image]

Comment: Thanks so much this looks very similar to my rig. Ill see if it works tommorow.

Comment: Alright this fixed like 90% of the problem. I know the eyes aren't seated In the eyelids correctly however, it is now manageable. Thank you so much for your help, you're a lifesaver.